# Можно ли задать внешний ключ в JSON-поле PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, foreign-key

Можно ли привязать ключи к *JSON*-полю к другим таблицам?

Пример: поле `data` вида `{"parameter1": value1, "parameter2": value2}`.  При этом, если есть значение `parameter1`, то оно должно быть привязано к определённой таблице, и соответственно значение не может быть «абы какое», а подвязано именно к другой таблице.

Делается ли такое вообще в *JSON*-полях на уровне ядра СУБД, без написания вручную кода проверок в обход базы данных?

Comment: Перефразируя [афоризм](https://twitter.com/compscifact/status/534383987624792064) Генри Спенсера, *если вы соврёте реляционной модели, рано или поздно она вам отомстит.*

Answer (score 0):

Насколько мне известно, таких возможностей нет.  И вообще это нарушение
правил нормализации данных.  Как вариант, можно добавить генерируемую
колонку и сделать её внешним ключом:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
)
;

CREATE TABLE t2 (
  id    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
, v     JSONB   NOT NULL
, t1_id INTEGER REFERENCES t1(id)
                GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CAST(v->'id' AS INTEGER)) STORED
)
;
```